# When can $n^k+k$ be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

For what positive integers $k$ does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that $n^k+k$ is a perfect square?

Certainly for all $k$ such that $k+1$ is a perfect square, since we can substitute $n=1$.

For $k=2$, we have that $n^2+2$ is a perfect square, but modulo $4$ this cannot occur. For other even values of $k$, we get that two perfect squares must differ by $k$, which restricts the possibility to just $n=1$, and we covered that in the previous paragraph.

So the hard case remains with odd values of $k$.

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but brilliant question,I love it! :D

Comment: Also, it is clear that one can take k=1

Comment: There are no solutions for $2\le n\le10^{~5}$ and odd $k\le25$.

Comment: For $k\ge2$, there is a solution to the similar $n^k-k=y^2$ as $2^7-7=11^2$. More generally, for $n^k+h=y^2$ with $2\leq n\leq 10^5$ and $k\leq 10$, then for small $\text{Abs}(h)\leq 10$ the following are squares, $$2^3 + 1,\; 3^3 - 2,\; 5^3 - 4,\; 6^3 + 9,\; 32^3 - 7,\; 40^3 + 9,\; 46^3 + 8,\; 2^5 + 4,\; 8^5 - 7,\; 2^7 - 7$$ It would be hard to rigorously prove the smallest $\text{Abs}(h)$ for each $k$. (**P.S.** I was hoping there might be a huge $n$ with a small $h$, but that's the best within the range.)

Comment: It seems the following. We can show that there is no such $n$ when $k=27$. Indeed, suppose that there exist natural numbers $n$ and $m$ and such that $n^{27}+27=m^2$. Then $(n^9+3)(n^{18}-n^9+9)=m^2$. Put $a=GCD(n^9+3,n^{18}-n^9+9)$. It is easy to show that $a|3$. If $a=3$ then $3|n$. Therefore $3^3|m^2$. But $3^4\not |m^2$, that is impossible. Hence $a=1$. Therefore $n^{18}-n^9+9=l^2$ for some natural $l$. Then $l< n^9$. But $(n^9-1)^2= n^{18}-2n^9+1< n^{18}-n^9+9$, a contradiction. A volunteer can try to generalize this proof for $k=(pa)^p$, where $a$ is natural and $p$ is prime.

Comment: If my program is correct then for $k=3$ and $n\le 2\cdot 10^6$ the only solution is $n=2$.

Comment: @alex I am confused. $n=2$ and $k=3$ gives $n^k+k=11$, which is not a square.

Comment: @lucian except for $k=1$

Comment: @Peter: Yes, of course. $($This has already been mentioned in the OP$)$.

Comment: For $2\le k\le 30$ and $2\le n \le 10^8$, there are no solutions.

Comment: @Peter Opps, sorry. It must be written "n=1" instead of "n=2".

Comment: For $2\le k \le 1000$ and $2\le n \le 10^5$, there are no solutions.

Comment: If $k \ge 5$, then a non-trivial solution must be greater than $10^{40}$.

Comment: The OP is right that the case $k$ even can be ruled out. In the argument for $k\ge 4$, it should be pointed out that for $n\ge 2$, we have $n^k\ge 2^k \ge k^2$, so $k$ is the difference of two squares, from which the smaller is at least $k^2$ (this is the missing point), and this is impossible because of $(k+1)^2-k^2=2k+1>k$

Comment: If $k\equiv 2\ (\ mod\ 4\ )$, we can also argue modulo $4$, which was done by the OP in the case $k=2$.

Comment: If $k=3$, then $n$ must be greater than $2*10^9$ to produce a non-trivial solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $k=3$ asks about $y^2=n^3+3$, which is a special case of the Mordell equation, $y^2=n^3+A$. A tremendous amount of work has been done on the Mordell equation, and solutions have been tabulated for large ranges of values of $A$, for example, [here](http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+). At that site you will find it stated that $y^2=n^3+3$ has only the solution $n=1$.

Comment: The case $k=7$ is resolved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4100427/finding-the-solutions-of-an-equation-in-positive-intgers?noredirect=1) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1569360p9628308) which you may wish to add an outline of the proof in your answer. I think we need a different trick for $k=5$.

Comment: @The, thanks for the links. You are welcome to post an answer here, outlining the proof for $k=7$, but I think it's enough to have the link here to the resolution there – why should we have the same material on this website in two different places?

Comment: The AoPS answer seems to take a different approach so I was initially hoping to add that. However, I don't think I should post a separate answer for $k=7$ as these are just individual cases so it might make sense to collate these cases into one answer (and then I can delete the comments here).

Comment: For $k=5$, this paper [A Note on Diophantine Equation $Y^2+k=X^5$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2005333?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) is close, but the author only considers $k>0$.

Comment: @The, I'll think about it.